# Почему итератор python выводит только первое ключ-значение словаря?

Tags: python, циклы, словарь

Есть код итерации словаря, при выполнении которого итератор проходит только по первым ключ-значениям, хотя в словаре их больше. Почему так и как это исправить?

**Код**

```
address_book_file = open("address_book_file", "rb")  # Открытие файла с словарем
dict_contact = pickle.load(address_book_file)  #Загрузка файла
for name, address in dict_contact.items():  # Итерация словаря
    print(dict_contact)   # Весь словарь
    print(name, address)  # Вывод итерации
```

**Вывод**

```
{'Mom': 'Mom1@rop.org', 'Dad': 'Daddy@rop.org', 'Sam': 'Sam@drop.box', 'kek': 'kekov@kek.org'}
Mom Mom1@rop.org
```

p.s
Пробовал играться с `keys()` и `values()`, но всё тщетно

upd

**Больше кода**

```
def search_contact():
    address_book_file = open("address_book_file", "rb")
    file_empty = os.path.getsize("address_book_file") == 0
    if not file_empty:
        search_name = input("Введите имя для поиска: ")
        dict_contact = pickle.load(address_book_file)
        for name, address in dict_contact.items():
            print(dict_contact)
            print(name, address)
            if search_name == name:
                print('\nКонтакт: {0}, с адресом {1}'.format(search_name, dict_contact[name]))
            else:
                print('Этого здесь нет')
                return
    else:
        print('Нет контактов')
    address_book_file.close()
```

Comment: А это что выводит `print(len(dict_contact.items()))`? У вас там точно нет break/return/quit/sys.exit в цикле?

Comment: Всё должно работать в таком виде, чего-то вы недоговариваете

Comment: @gil9red Выводит 4, добавил больше кода, надеюсь это поможет в решении проблемы

Comment: @CrazyElf. Добавил больше кода, надеюсь это поможет

Comment: Я ещё слаб в этом всём, если я что-то делаю не так, пожалуйста, сообщите об этом!

Comment: Если в первой итерации не выполнится условие search_name == name, то сразу выполнится ветка с return, и цикл прервется.

Comment: Вам не надо перебирать весь словарь, чтобы найти в нём нужный ключ. Проверка наличия ключа в словаре `if search_name in dict_contact:`, получить значение по ключу `address = dict_contact[search_name]`

Comment: @insolor and CrazyElf, Благодарю!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итерация у вас завершается досрочно из-за `return` в блоке `else:`

```
else:
    print('Этого здесь нет')
    return # после этого итерация прекращается
```

Лучше не перебирать все ключи словаря для поиска нужного ключа, а сразу моментально проверить наличие ключа в словаре (для чего словари собственно и предназначены):

```
if search_name in dict_contact:
    print('\nКонтакт: {0}, с адресом {1}'.format(search_name, dict_contact[search_name]))
else:
    print('Этого здесь нет')
```

И файл лучше открывать с помощью менеджера контекста, тогда он потом закроется автоматически по завершении блока кода:

```
with open("address_book_file", "rb") as address_book_file:
    # остальной код
```

Comment: Стоит добавить as в блок кода с with. 
with open("address_book_file", "rb") as address_book_file:
    # остальной код

Comment: @MMbest1 Да, спасибо, что-то я as упустил